# io.Reader endless loop with fmt.Fscan

Tags: go

Not sure why, but my `io.Reader` implementation appears to be flawed somehow?

The docs for `io.Reader` state that returning a non-zero byte count and a non-nil error should be ok:

> It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call or return the error (and n == 0) from a subsequent call. An instance of this general case is that a Reader returning a non-zero number of bytes at the end of the input stream may return either err == EOF or err == nil. The next Read should return 0, EOF.
>
> Callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before considering the error err. Doing so correctly handles I/O errors that happen after reading some bytes and also both of the allowed EOF behaviors.

But this doesn't work for `fmt.Fscan`, instead hanging the program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

type Byte byte

func (b Byte) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if len(p) == 0 {
        return 0, io.ErrShortBuffer
    }
    p[0] = byte(b)
    return 1, io.EOF
}

func main() {
    var n int
    b := Byte('9')
    z, err := fmt.Fscan(b, &n)
    fmt.Println(n, z, err)
}
```

Of course, it works if i instead return a zero byte count with `io.EOF` separately:

```golang
type Byte struct {
    v   byte
    eof bool
}

func (b *Byte) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if len(p) == 0 {
        return 0, io.ErrShortBuffer
    }
    if b.eof {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }
    p[0] = b.v
    b.eof = true
    return 1, nil
}

func main() {
    var n int
    b := Byte{v: '9'}
    z, err := fmt.Fscan(&b, &n)
    fmt.Println(n, z, err)
}
```

Is there a flaw in my original implementation, or should i simply not depend on this particular bit of documented behavior of `io.Reader` and always separately return `0, io.EOF` when there is no more data to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmt.Scanf` does handle returning the count and `io.EOF` correctly, but your reader continues to return values even after `io.EOF`.

Because the scanner implementation relies on using `io.ReadFull`, which uses `io.ReadAtLeast`, you are going need a more complete implementation to work with repeated reads. You can test this by taking your extended version which tracks EOF, and return `io.EOF` on the first `Read` and it will still work with `fmt.Fscan` as expected.

Key excerpts from the docs:

`io.ReadFull`:

> ... it does not treat an EOF from Read as an error to be reported

`io.ReadAtLeast`:

> The error is EOF only if no bytes were read.

Because these `io` helpers need to interpret `io.EOF` themselves, their callers can only look for the actual data returned, and since your reader continues to return data, they will repeat the call indefinitely. This is easily demonstrated by calling `io.ReadAll` repeatedly on your reader, which returns another value every time.

```
b := Byte('9')
fmt.Println(io.ReadAll(b))
fmt.Println(io.ReadAll(b))
fmt.Println(io.ReadAll(b))

// [57] <nil>
// [57] <nil>
// [57] <nil>
```

https://go.dev/play/p/It_4BWLsSP8