# Why does the (json.Decoder).Decode not return a string value until it receives the next byte?

Tags: go

Consider the following `decode` function:

```golang
type Message struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
}

// decode uses the json.Decoder to decode the given JSON stream. 
// It returns the first error value (including nil) that is returned 
// by the (json.Decoder).Decode method. If (json.Decoder).Decode does 
// not return within 100ms, then decode returns a timeout error.
func decode(jsonStream string) error {
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    defer r.Close()
    defer w.Close()

    errch := make(chan error)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r)

    go func() {
        var m Message
        err := decoder.Decode(&m)
        errch <- err
    }()

    w.Write([]byte(jsonStream))

    select {
    case err := <-errch:
        return err
        // Arbitrary timeout (anything that is larger than the time it takes to
        // process the stream data).
    case <-time.After(100 * time.Millisecond):
        return errors.New("timeout")
    }
}
```

## Test Cases

Now, let's put the `decode` function to use with a few sample stream snippets:

```golang
func main() {
    streams := []string{
        `{"foo":"bar"}`,
        `"hello"`,
        `"hello"{`,
    }

    for _, stream := range streams {
        if err := decode(stream); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", stream, err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s: ok\n", stream)
    }
}
```

## Result

```bash
1. {"foo":"bar"}: ok
2. "hello": timeout
3. "hello"{: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.Message
```

## Observations

- `{"foo":"bar"}`: The `(json.Decoder).Decode` method returned `nil` as expected since the JSON stream contains a JSON object that matches the `Message` type that we are decoding into. The fact that the stream does not have any data after the said JSON object means that `(json.Decoder).Decode` returned immediately when it received the closing curly bracket of the object.
- `"hello"`: We got a timeout error, meaning that `(json.Decoder).Decode` did not return. This is unexpected. I expected a decode error for the following reasons:

  - A string is not compatible with the `Message` type that we are decoding into.
  - Similar to how the beginning and end of a JSON object is
    clearly defined by a pair of curly brackets, the
    beginning and end of a string is clearly defined by a pair of double
    quotes.
- `"hello"{`: Another byte was added to the stream, simulating the beginning of the next JSON object. Now the `(json.Decoder).Decode` processed the string and returned the error that was expected in the previous case.
- If we replace the line `var m Message` in the `decode` function above with `var m string`, the same behavior is observed regarding the timing of when `(json.Decoder).Decode` returns. While we no longer expect a decode error when it receives a string in the stream, it still only returns when it receives the byte after the complete string.

## Question

Why does `(json.Decoder).Decode` only return when it receives the next byte after a complete string? Is there anything indeterministic about `"some-string"` in a stream?

Comment: Interesting. If you close the write end of the pipe after sending the data, it works fine. That means, the decoder is waiting to read from the input after it reads a complete string. It might be waiting to read the additional spaces, but that should not really happen. Looks like an edge case bug.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to talk about that part. When I first became suspicious of the behavior and created the minimal reproducible example, I first used `strings.Reader` instead of `io.Pipe`. That didn't demonstrate the issue though because `strings.Reader` is closed after its string is read and, like you discovered, the json.Decoder works in that case as expected.

Comment: this sounds familiar, IIRC there's a case where the EOF is taken by a buffer implementation, so you need one more read to fail to actually close the whole thing. maybe I can find what I was looking at ...

Comment: @JimB, there is no EOF here though. The decoder is attempting to read beyond a complete JSON lexical element. It might be waiting for a ':', or attempting to eat up empty spaces. But it should've stopped reading after the second quote.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76212940/io-reader-endless-loop-with-fmt-fscan/76213110#76213110, but `json` doesn't use `ReadAtLeast` like I suspected.  If you look at the code, there are only "end" scan tokens for arrays and objects, so the scanner is blocked refilling the buffer waiting to see if there is more after the string value. A simple string alone is not a normal thing to have json encoded, so there's no special case for it, but you can test that it does work with an array too.

Comment: A json string is a valid token to scan though. The decoder should be able to scan strings, numbers, bool, and null

Comment: if you look at the various `stateXXX` functions in [`json/scanner.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/468bc941886ae83b8d16af5deaaf12ea5cabb05b/src/encoding/json/scanner.go#L215) (<- state of maser on 2023-11-20), you can see that the functions for bool, null and string are processed in a way similar to numbers, and all return a `scanContinue` even when reaching the known end of the token. So they all expect one extra byte (or EOF) before "signaling" that a complete value was scanned. See [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/JFTZnWXOV_j): first 5 values trigger "timeout"

Comment: for comparison: using [`github.com/go-json-experiment/json`](https://github.com/go-json-experiment/json) works as expected ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/gaOGeX1fgmW)) : only the number litteral triggers a "timeout" error (number have this specificity in json: they are the only values which aren't "self-delimited", the scanner must read a non number char or reach EOF to know that it has scanned the entire value). The module interface changes from `encoding/json` though, it is not a drop in replacement.

Comment: Ah cool, so we can expect this issue to be fixed in `encoding/json/v2` whenever that is released as part of the standard library. It makes sense that the scanner can't predict the end of a number.

Comment: Given that https://github.com/go-json-experiment/json works as expected, I assume that the Go team is aware of the issue discussed here. Does anyone know of an open bug report that we can link to as an answer to the question here? If you find a bug report and want to add an answer here then I am happy to accept it. :)